# Can I use latex in my ipywidget dropdown which was made on Google colab platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use latex equations for dropdown `ipywidget`. I want to show some Greek symbols(as theta), but I can't achieve it

I'm using `matplotlib` for `polarplots`, before, I use the `sintax r'$\latex$`' for compile symbols on traditional plots, however, here doesn't work.

My code

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cardioide_widget(a=4,cardioide=1):
  
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
  axp = plt.subplot(111, projection="polar")


  # Definición de variables para gráficas
  def c(cardioide,theta):
    if cardioide == 1: 
      return a+a*np.cos(theta)
    elif cardioide == 2: 
      return a-a*np.cos(theta)
    elif cardioide == 3: 
      return a+a*np.sin(theta)
    elif cardioide == 4: 
      return a-a*np.sin(theta)

  theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)

  #Gráfica en coordenadas polares
  axp.plot(theta,c(cardioide,theta))
  
  #Límites para los ejes polares
  axp.set_rmax(10.05)
   


  plt.show()


widgets.interact(cardioide_widget, a=(0.5,5.0,0.1),cardioide=[(r'$r = a + a cos(\theta)$',1),('r = a - a cos(theta)',2),('r = a + a sen(theta)',3),('r = a - a sen(theta)',4)]);
```

I'm just trying for the first term on the dropdown `menú`

```
(r'$r = a + a cos(\theta)$',1)
```

[image: chart]